# How to killing the son of a fork properly

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am doing my own shell but I have problems during the execution.

After my fork, I do an execve of a file, but if the file is not a binary then my son doesn't exit so I have an infinite loop.
I know I can exit() my child but I dont want to use it.

Is there any other possibilites to kill it ?

I already tried to do `kill(pid, SIGTERM);` but it also kill the parent.

Do you have any idea ?

This is my code :

```
int     son(int *fd_in, int p[2], t_list *cmd, char **env, int pid)
{
  (void)env;
  signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
  if (g_fd != -1)
    {
      dup2(g_fd, 0);
      g_fd = -1;
    }
  dup2(*fd_in, 0);
  if (cmd->act != ENDACT && cmd->act != LEFT && cmd->act != DLEFT)
    dup2(p[1], 1);
  close(p[0]);
  if ((execve(cmd->av[0], cmd->av, env)) == -1)
    {
      kill(pid, SIGTERM);
    }
  return (0);
}

t_list      *execute_pipe(t_list *cmd, int *fd_in, int *status, char **env)
{
  int       p[2];
  pid_t     pid;

  *fd_in = 0;
  while (cmd->act != -1)
    {
      pipe(p);
      if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
    return (NULL);
      else if (pid == 0)
    son(fd_in, p, cmd, env, pid);
      else
    {
      close(p[1]);
      *fd_in = p[0];
      if (cmd->act != PIPE)
        {
          while (waitpid(pid, status, WUNTRACED) > 0);
          return (cmd);
        }
      cmd = cmd->next;
    }
    }
  while (waitpid(pid, status, WUNTRACED) > 0);
  return (cmd);
}
```

Comment: Why not `execve(...); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`?

Comment: Sending SIGTERM to a child process shouldn't kill the parent. Can you run this in a debugger?

Comment: Actually, looking at the code poses a fascinating question, what *does* happen when you try to kill `pid zero`?

Comment: Besides I do not understand why this: "*but I dont want to use it.*", take this hint: Log the value of `pid` inside the child before calling `kill()` then RTFM for `kill()`.

Comment: @EOF With pid 0, the signal is sent to all processes in the process group.

Comment: @Wintermute: ...which I guess is the answer.

Comment: When I try to do kill(0, SIGTERM) I have the same behaviour, it also kill my parent.

Comment: You **do** `kill(0, ...)`! *sigh*

Comment: Yes I know that kill(pid, SIGKILL) is the same thing that kill(0, SIGKILL) but I only tried that people said me to do.

Comment: @EOF Actually, I think your first comment is the answer. Unless I'm being blind (which, admittedly, would not be without precedent), the child process is trying to commit suicide. `exit` should be just fine.

Comment: This is the output I have right now : `(danilo_d - /home/danilo_d/semestre2/PSU_2014_42sh 0)$>ls
42sh  auteur  include  lol  Makefile  sources  test  titi
(danilo_d - /home/danilo_d/semestre2/PSU_2014_42sh 1)$>./lol
fish: Job 1, “./42sh ” terminated by signal SIGTERM (Polite quit request)`

Comment: Erm... Isn't the better solution to have the child handle the infinite loop? How is the parent going to know if this is encountered?

Comment: Actually ,I am not allowed to use exit for this project.

Comment: @DimitriDanilov: Alright, I'll give you a hint: Trace back the origin of `son()`'s `pid`-argument to where `son()` is called...

Comment: "*I am not allowed to use exit*": Use `_exit()` or `abort()` or `raise(SIGKILL)` or `kill(getpid(), SIGKILL)`.

Comment: If I change the groupe pid of the child, would it work? I don't have the right to use _exit() and abort().

Comment: Thanks ! If I use kill(getpid(), SIGKILL) it works fine!

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/694576/alk You should write that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally to kill my process I did `kill(getpid(), SIGTERM)` and it worked well.

Answer (score -2):

I know you already stated that you tried it, but sending a SIGTERM or a SIGKILL to it is the best way in my opinion.

Using the "kill(pid, SIGKILL);" syntax should absolutely not kill any process other than that which is equal to pid. 
The only advice I have is to make sure that the pid being used in the kill call is that of the son, and not the parent.

Also check that the son's pid is not being set equal to the reference to the parent's pid, as you might think you're passing in the son's pid and really it points to the parent's pid data. Just my thoughts.

See the following man page: http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill

Comment: It's `fork()` so no, there is no problem with a "reference" to the parent's pid.